# prove $x+1 = 1+x$ using Peano axioms

Tags: induction, peano-axioms

I wanna prove that $x+1 = 1+x$ (**without considering "$x+0=x$",and Im using the old definition of Peano axioms**)
This is **my try**:
Using this basis:

> $(1):1+x = x^+$
> $(2):x^+ +y=(x+y)^+$

Actually my idea is if numbers succesor are equal then actual numbers are equal too. (based on Peano axioms)
$$(1+x)^+ = 1^+ + x = (1+1)+x$$
and
$$(x+1)^+ = x^+ +1 = (1+x)+1$$
But I stucked in how to show that this two are equal.

Somebody help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We will prove by induction that $x+1=x^+$.

*Basis*: $1+1=1^+$, from (1).

*Induction step*: assume $x+1=x^+$ and prove that $x^++1=(x^+)^+$.

By (2): $x^++1 = (x+1)^+ = (x^+)^+$ using induction hypotheses and [substitution for equality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Equality_and_its_axioms).

Having proved that $x+1=x^+$, for every $x$, we use (1) and transitivity and symmetry of equality to conclude that:

> $x+1=1+x$.

Comment: Thanks!Clear and easy to understand.

Comment: @program_craft - you are welcome :-)